# Is it possible for an organism that is polypoloid with an odd number of sets of chromosomes (e.g. 5 sets) to be fertile?

Tags: evolution, polyploidy

Is this possible, since there is five sets, there would be an unequal separation of homologous chromosomes during anaphase I of meiosis?

Comment: what do you think? have you thought through this question? have you looked somewhere for the answer? is this homework?

Comment: I think it is a good question +1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. There seems however to always come up with a cost in fertility eventually of the order of 2/3!

You should have a look at [Ramsey and Schemske 1998](http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/221716.pdf). I don't remember it well enough to make a good summary (maybe someone else could do that?!) but it is a classical article. Here is a sentence from their abstract

> In contrast to the common claim that triploids are sterile, our results indicate that the triploid bridge pathway can contribute significantly to autopolyploid formation regardless of the mating system, and to allopolyploid formation in outcrossing taxa.

Comment: The question was about odd numbers of sets, and talks about unequal separation, therefore I assume the question uses the word "odd" in the mathematical sense of having a remainder when divided by 2, rather than "unusual" - can you edit your answer?

Comment: @BryanKrause Ooops, I wrote 'tetra' instead of 'tri' by mistake (fixed now, thanks). I suppose this is what made you think I misunderstood the question. I understood the question correctly I think.

Comment: Indeed that was it; thanks for updating and for the additional quote from the article. Any other details you could add to your answer on how this mechanistically works out would improve your answer even more (e.g., the ploidy of the gametes and resulting offspring).

Answer (score 0):

Triploid and pentaploid Rhododendron and deciduous azalea are sometimes fertile.

In our flow cytometry testing of seedlings from triploid Rhododendrons, the offspring can be diploid, triploid, tetraploid, pentaploid or aneuploids normally between triploid and tetraploid.  The seedlings of pentaploids tend to be aneuploids between tetraploid and pentaploid.

One can think of a fertile triploids as producing 1x to 2x gametes centered around 1.5x. Fertile pentaploid seem to produce gametes between 2x to 3x centered around 2.5x.

In general the question is not whether gametes are produced from odd ploidy but instead whether the gametes are successful in combining to create a viable seed.

We have many seedlings growing in our yard where the parents were triploid and pentaploid deciduous azaleas.

See the early work of C D Darlington on the meiosis of triploids.

Note: In our yard is a very fertile triploid deciduous azalea called 'Anna's Smile' bred by Ed Mezitt of Weston Nursery. This year we successfully crossed onto this azalea using pollen from diploids, triploids, tetraploids, hexaploids, and octaploids. 40 of the attempted 45 crosses produced seed. This triploid produces open pollinated seed. Another triploid deciduous azalea produced by Ed Mezitt called 'Deep Rose' also appears to be fertile.

Note: We crossed Rhododendron flammeum (diploid) X Rhododendron atlanticum (tetraploid) to produce triploid seedlings. One of triploid seedlings from this cross is semi-fertile. We have a dozen or so seedlings from this semi-fertile triploid.

Note: A pentaploid seedling from a fertile triploid seems to also be very fertile. We have 50 or so seedlings from this fertile pentaploid.

Note: The tetraploid Rhododendron cultivar 'Countess of Derby' is documented to have 2 triploid parents, namely 'Pink Pearl' and Cynthia'. The pentaploid Rhododendron 'White Ginger' is documented to have a triploid seed parent and a tetraploid pollen parent, namely 'Phyllis Korn' and 'Trude Webster' where 'Trude Webster' is documented to be 'Countess of Derby' selfed. So 'White Ginger' has triploids in the background of both parents.